# how to remove headers using piggybank?

Tags: apache-pig, bigdata

I have a directory which contains 10 files and I want to remove the headers from the files present in directory and while executing using piggybank, I am getting an error. Is there any other way which can remove header from all the files present in a directory.My code is:-

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
input = LOAD 'insurance_data' using CSVExcelStorage(
    ',','default','NOCHANGE','SKIP_INPUT_HEADER')
as (population:int, private:int,public:int,uninsecured:int);
dump input;
```

The error which I am getting is :-

> 2016-09-13 14:01:48,239 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer -
>   exception during parsing: Error during parsing.   mismatched input 'input' expecting EOF Failed to parse:
>     mismatched input 'input' expecting
>   EOF   at
>   org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:179)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1688)   at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1421)    at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:354)    at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:379)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:365)     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:769)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)     at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:613)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:158)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) 2016-09-13
>   14:01:48,250 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR
>   1200:   mismatched input 'input'
>   expecting EOF Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1473800504430.log

Answer (score 0):

'input' is a keyword.Reference [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#reserved-keywords).Change the name of the relation 'input' to something else.

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
A = LOAD 'insurance_data' USING CSVExcelStorage(',','default','NOCHANGE','SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') as (population:int, private:int,public:int,uninsecured:int);
DUMP A;
```

Comment: It's still not working. I am getting an error:-                             2016-09-13 15:57:21,663 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. Could not resolve CSVExcelStorage using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse:

Comment: Do you have piggybank.jar in the following location /usr/lib/pig/? The error means the CSVExcelStorage function was resolved more likely due to not being able to register the jar file.

Comment: Yes u r right, I got an error while registering in piggy.jar but I have the biggybank at this location.. I don't know why it's showing an error

Comment: Is insurance_data a directory or file?Specify the full path to the directory.